# Use XMLStarlet in Azure DevOps Bash task

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xmlstarlet

I want to use `xmlstartlet` within a Bash task in Azure DevOps to edit the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
    <PostFlow name="PostFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PostFlow>
```

I want to make this code to the below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
    <PostFlow name="PostFlow">
        <Request>
            <Step>
                <Name>EV-ExtractParameters</Name>
            </Step>
        </Request>
        <Response/>
    </PostFlow>
```

But stuck at getting to install XMLstarlet in the build server. Has anyone been able to use this in Azure DevOps Bash task?

I have tried to use an agent demand, but that didn't work.

Comment: Do you hosted agent?

Comment: Yes. I have only hosted agent access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Microsoft Hosted agents the `xmlstarlet` tool not installed in the machine, so you can't just use it.

You need to add a Bash task to install the tool, then you can use it.

Example in the `.yaml` pipeline to the Bash task:

```
-bash: |
  sudo apt-get install xmlstarlet
```

Then use it with the command `xmlstarlet [<options>] <command>`.

Comment: Done. Thank you :)

Comment: In the xmlstarlet command the edited xml is present in stdout. I tried this command to push it to a file, but it isn't working. Anything am doing wrong? xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
 --subnode '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request' -t elem -n "Step" \ 
 --subnode '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request/Step' -t elem -n "Name" ./default.xml >temp.xml

Comment: @AK123 I I really don't know :/ sorry!

Comment: `sudo apt-fast install -y xmlstarlet` worked for me in azure pipeline